# How to use debugpy in VScode to debug remote python server?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, remote-debugging

I've used `"type": "python"` to debug remote python servers. Now I'm seeing this warning in `launch.json`:

> This configuration will be deprecated soon. Please replace `python` with `debugpy` to use the new Python Debugger extension.

[image]

My original setting:

```
{
      "type": "python",
      "request": "attach",
      "name": "attach remote",
      "host": "192.168.1.101",
      "port": 8765,
      "pathMappings": [
        {
          "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/...",
          "remoteRoot": "/usr/app/..."
        }
      ],
      "justMyCode": false
    },
```

When I switch to `"type": "debugpy"` I get the following error on the "port" and "host" fields:

> Property port is not allowed.

[image]

So the question is: **how to add the port and host information to complete the migration of the debug configuration?**

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

So it turns out it's pretty easy: replace the `"port"` and `"host"` attributes with `"connect"`, so if your configuration was:

```
{
      "type": "python",
      "request": "attach",
      "name": "attach remote",
      "host": "192.168.1.101",
      "port": 8765,
      "pathMappings": [
        {
          "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/...",
          "remoteRoot": "/usr/app/..."
        }
      ],
      "justMyCode": false
    },
```

It becomes:

```
{
      "type": "debugpy",
      "request": "attach",
      "name": "attach remote",
      "connect": { "host": "192.168.1.101", "port": 8765 },
      "pathMappings": [
        {
          "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/...",
          "remoteRoot": "/usr/app/..."
        }
      ],
      "justMyCode": false
    },
```